# How to get property name from within getter/setter of that property?

Tags: c#, properties

Let's say we have a property as below

```
public string SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        var propName = "SomeProperty";
        return "<" + propName + ">";
    }
}
```

How can I set value of the above variable `propName` to be the property name by reading from the assembly information itself?

**Edit**

Why we need this?

I'm using the WPF `d:DataContext` as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314103/how-to-set-a-value-to-display-for-bound-properties-in-wpf-design-mode/4316450#4316450) which will help me to display a 'design-mode' value for bound properties - very often, the bound values are displayed as empty string in design mode. And in the 'design-mode' data-context class, I want to return the property name for every binding properties I may have.

Hope this would explain your concerns.

Comment: Please clarify where you'd want to do that.

Comment: and why are you doing this ? is there any specific requirement

Comment: So you want to make a property, that returns it's own name?

Comment: You are on the wrong direction, I'm afraid. Please tell us your initial requirement if possible.

Comment: @Every one: Hi, I have updated my question to explain why I need it; it's about showing the bound property names in design-mode in VS2010 IDE

Comment: Thank you so much for this question. I just started asking the same thing. +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a while I figure out a solution as below, which is quite convenient to me.

```
    string SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return GetDesignModeValue(() => this.SomeProperty);
        }
    }

    string GetDesignModeValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var propName = (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
        var value = string.Format(
            "<{0}>"
            , propName);
        return value;
    }
```

So, from now on, it is much much easier for us to show the  binding properties' `mocking` value when in design mode.

I hope you would find it helpful somedays!

Comment: When using Visual Studio 2015 you simply can use the operator keyword [nameof(this.SomeProperty)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a reliable way for doing that at runtime, but you can use [`MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx) and throw away the first four characters.

This approach has some flaws: running the binary through an obfuscation tool may cause the method to get renamed. Additionally, the method may be inlined and cause problems (if you just use `Remove` on the string without checking the length, it may even cause unexpected crashes in the Release build that can be difficult to reproduce in Debug mode).

If your code follows a pattern and you need to generate a bunch of properties like that, it's better to use a compile-time approach like a code generator or an aspect-oriented programming framework.

Answer (score 1):

this should also work BUT i am not sure why you require this

```
public string SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
            StackFrame[] fr = st.GetFrames();
            if (fr != null)
            {
                var propName = fr[0].GetMethod().Name.Substring(3, fr[0].GetMethod().Name.Length);
                return "<" + propName + ">";
            }

            return "SomeProperty";

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have update my question to explain why I need this. Thank you Saurabh

Comment: This worked for me, although I used `Name.Substring(4)` as they're prefixed with `set_` or `get_` - and you don't need the second parameter

Answer (score -3):

It's possible to pass the name of the property to the getter.

if **MyObj** is the object and if **PropName** is the variable holding the name of the property, then the following code is doing the job:

```
eval("Object.defineProperty(MyObj, PropName, { " + 
     "get : function() { return(\"the prop name is " + PropName + "\"); } });");
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C#...