# How to get design time data in silverlight/wpf designer?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I want to have my user controls have design time data.  If I add the data/datacontext using the constructor, I can see the data in the control from a different view that contains the control.

If I set the DataContext from xaml, I can see it when I'm designing the control, but I see nothing in a control that hosts the control.

So is there any example of how to get design time data to show up in a control if it is being edited, or it's parent is being edited?  Or anything that lists the rules of then the constructor is run/not run from the designer?  I'm trying to set a DesignViewModel with the data, and at runtime use the actual view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then it's answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314103/how-to-set-a-value-to-display-for-bound-properties-in-wpf-design-mode/4316450#4316450) question

Comment: That's pretty cool, unfortunately it only works on the currently edited control.  So if I have a BookView, when I'm designing BookView then I can see the data.  But if I have another control that contains a BookView, and I am editing the other control, all of BookView is blank and doesn't have the design data..

Comment: It looks like this is by design, so you can use different sample data in the containing control.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/555272/silverlight-forum-designcontext-and-d-designinstance-discarded-in-nested-usercontrols