# WPF, How do I see what I'm doing in the editor after using Bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, binding

It's my first time using WPF, I'm still getting used to the controls. I have a couple of textboxes, each having a Binding to a string somewhere. Works great when running the program, but in the editor.. all I see is blank emptyness. When I mouse-over I can see the border of the textbox, but having to mouseover to find all my elements in my program.. well, that's not a nice way to design a layout.

Is there any way to have 'default' text visible in the editor? Some parameter I'm missing, some border I can activate only during editing mode, heck, -any- way I can see what I'm doing without influencing what the program looks like when being ran?

```
//Properly binds and displays text, but invisible in the editor.
<TextBlock Height="48" Margin="26, 191, 0, 0" Text="{Binding FirstTextBox} Width="175">
```

ANSWER::
After hearing the keyword 'Design-Time', [How to set a value to display for bound properties in WPF design mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314103/how-to-set-a-value-to-display-for-bound-properties-in-wpf-design-mode) brought me to the proper answer.

Comment: I think you're looking for [Design-Time Data support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set DataContext to your Model. If you want to see your property value in editor.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Did you try by using **FallbackValue**?
Here is an example from other post to set a default text visible as you asked.
[WPF Binding - Default value for empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567588/wpf-binding-default-value-for-empty-string)