# How to make XAML designer ( VS 2010 ) to bind UserControl properties to inner XAML elements?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I created a UserControl with orientation property.
All the orientation work should be done by inner stack panel, so I bound it to the property.

This works fine at run time, but the WPF designer shows default value of the stack panel ( vertical ) instead of the default value of the orientation property ( horizontal ).

Here is simplified example.
XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyWpf.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:MyWpf="clr-namespace:MyWpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="{Binding Path=Orientation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyWpf:MyUserControl}}}">
        <TextBlock>A</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>B</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>C</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty;

    static MyUserControl()
    {
        OrientationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "Orientation", typeof( Orientation ), typeof( MyUserControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( Orientation.Horizontal ) );
    }

    public Orientation Orientation
    {
        get
        {
            return (Orientation)GetValue( OrientationProperty );
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue( OrientationProperty, value );
        }
    }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The only solution I see is to include the Orientation into ViewModel (and use DesignData), but I want it to be clean. I hope there is something like DesignData, but for the control itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

[What approaches are available to dummy design-time data in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889966/what-approaches-are-available-to-dummy-design-time-data-in-wpf)

I'm guessing you could try setting `d:Orientation` on your `StackPanel`.

Most Binding extensions work their magic at run-time (sometimes you need that, some times at compile time). I'm not 100% but you could try with `{Binding ElementName=_userControl, Path=Orientation}` - but even if it 'works' I don't think that'd work for you since that's your custom property.

Here is a link about something similar which explains a bit (but doesn't help your case).
[WPF TemplateBinding vs RelativeSource TemplatedParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Unfortunately there is no d:Orientation design time attribute.  Also I tried to bind using ElementName, it didn't help.  I didn't show it in the example, but I am using DesignData attribute on UserControl to display data from ViewModel in the designer. But I want to separate ViewModel's data from the control's properties. It means I cannot use d:DataContext ( or d:DesignData ) for setting Orientation.  The TemplateBinding is new for me, need to read more about it. UPD: Sorry about formating, trying to fix it.

Comment: DId you add the xmlns namespace for it ?

Comment: `TemplateBinding` is not for you - just to 'showcase' the similar issue (early vs late binding sort of).

Comment: Yes, it's there, in the example.

Comment: it does compile for me `(d:Orientation)` and it didn't complain of it. Though I don't have a good example to test the validity of it. But if it's there it should work. You put it on the StackPanel not the UserControl