# Is it possible to display data at design time in a treeview that uses binding at runtime?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Is it possible to display something in my treeview at design time and what would be the best way to achieve it?

Runtime works perfectly well and does display the data I want. However, I would like to have a more convenient display when designing than an empty area where the treeview is.

Thank you.

The treeview looks like this:

```
       <TreeView x:Name="tvConfig" Width="400" Height="300"  >

        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type demo:TvItemsSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

And make uses of this class:

```
Public Class TvItemsSource
 Public Property Items() As New List(Of TvItemsSource)
 Public Property Name() As String

 Public Sub New(Name As String)
    Me.Name = Name
 End Sub

End Class
```

I generated a small runtime data using the following piece of code:

```
Private _source As TvItemsSource
Private Sub LoadData()
  _source = New TvItemsSource("Root")
  _source.Items.Add(New TvItemsSource("Item 1"))
  _source.Items.Add(New TvItemsSource("Item 2 "))
    Dim ParentItem1 = New TvItemsSource("Parent 1")
    ParentItem1.Items.Add(New TvItemsSource("Enfant 1"))
    Dim ParentItem2 = New TvItemsSource("Parent 2")
    ParentItem2.Items.Add(New TvItemsSource("Enfant 2"))
    ParentItem1.Items.Add(ParentItem2)
    _source.Items.Add(ParentItem1)

    tvConfig.ItemsSource = _source.Items
End sub
```

edit: In the xaml of the treeview, I added the xmlns namespace of the application to declare the data type as :

```
xmlns:demo="clr-namespace:demo"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the ideal solution for my project by using this statement:

```
Dim IsDesignMode As Boolean = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(New DependencyObject())
```

The IsDesignMode variable does return true and anything therefore a listbox items source binded on a "Content" property would display the "Design Mode" items in the designer and the "Production" items when ran.

```
If IsDesignMode Then
        For I = 1 To 10
            Content.Add("DesignMode " & I)
        Next
    Else
        Content.Add("Production 1")
        Content.Add("Production 2")
        Content.Add("Production 3")
    End If
```

There are other way to do it.

Relevant: 
[SO: What approaches are available to dummy design-time data in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889966/what-approaches-are-available-to-dummy-design-time-data-in-wpf)

Also: 
[Simulating data in design mode in Microsoft Blend](http://galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007091401.html)