# Xaml at design time

Tags: wpf, xaml

I ran into this issues endless number of times: in order to see some template, binding outcome or many more I need to run application. Is any solution to prevent running apps and be able to see result? It drives me nuts especially when it comes to see *ListBoxItem's* template since *ListBox's* binding displays no rows untill I run the whole app.

Answer (score 2):

Use Design-Time data :)

Usually by declaring a different DataContext at design time like so:

```
<Grid d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DesignViewModel}}">
```

Notice the "extra" `d`.

[SO: Dummy Design Time Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889966/what-approaches-are-available-to-dummy-design-time-data-in-wpf)

[MSDN: Maximizing the Visual Designer’s Usage with Design-Time Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx)