# Binding simple list of integers in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I'm using the following XAML to create a simple list of DayOfMonth values:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding DayOfMonth}" SelectedValuePath="/">
  <ComboBoxItem>
    <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
  </ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>
    <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
  </ComboBoxItem>
  ...
  ...
</ComboBox>
```

The problem is that it doesn't select correct item (in fact it doesn't select any) in the ComboBox when the underlying ViewModel has one assigned to `DayOfMonth` property (property type is `Int32`). I have tried it without `<sys:Int32>` as well, i.e. directly using `<ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>` syntax, that doesn't work either.

**Note**: I'm looking for XAML-only solution.

**Edit**

Though it is not of much value, here is the property I'm binding my ComboBox to:

```
private int mDayOfMonth;
public int DayOfMonth 
{
    get { return mDayOfMonth; }
    set 
    {
        if (mDayOfMonth != value) 
        {
             mDayOfMonth = value;
             if (PropertyChanged != null) 
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DayOfMonth"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what does your code for the viewmodel and for the code behind of the view look like?

Comment: You want a XAML only solution, but you have a ViewModel class.  If so, why aren't you binding the ComboBox ItemsSource property to a property in the viewmodel (for the days in the month).

Comment: @slugster: The only relevant part in the ViewModel is that `Int32` property that this ComboBox is binding to.

Comment: @WaltRitscher: That's how MVVM generally works, right? XAML-only solution means that I don't want to use a for-loop to fill items in the ComboBox, but rather add them declaratively.

Comment: In MVVM you have a property of type ObservableCollection on your ViewModel (for example (DaysInCurrentMonth).  Fill the ObservableCollection in some manner and then bind the ComboBox.ItemsSource to the property.

Comment: @WaltRitscher: Rightly said. However my intent here is discover a design-time way of adding items to the ComboBox that I could use binding with.

Comment: If that's the case, then you should look into using design-time data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889966/what-approaches-are-available-to-dummy-design-time-data-in-wpf

Comment: @WaltRitscher: Perhaps I used wrong word there. I do not want to use design-time data, those only show in the designer. What I was after was to be able to add items to the ComboBox manually through XAML, and then bind the ComboBox's `SelectedValue` property to an `Int32` field of the `DataContext`. @octavioccl's answer already achieves that. Thanks for your interest and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare the interger values inside ComboBoxItems. Something like this should work:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding DayOfMonth}">
  <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>>
  <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
  ...
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: This somehow works. Had to remove `SelectedValuePath="/"` clause from ComboBox though. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The int values are still wrapped in an implicit ComboBoxItem

Comment: @WaltRitscher: Correct, but if I instead use `<ComboBoxItem>` myself in XAML, it will get nested in a double-`<ComboBoxItem>`. That's my guess though. Not sure if WPF is intelligent enough not to use implicit wrapping when the item type is a `ComboBoxItem` itself.

Comment: It won't get wrapped in another ComboBoxItem.  The ItemsContainerGenerator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx  is responsible for determining whether an implicit or explicit ComboBoxItem is used.   You should download XAMLSpy, it shows you the WPF visual tree.  That way you can see what XAML is actually rendered at runtime.