# Why does design time data not show up in Windows Phone project?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, design-time

Following the suggested solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889966/what-approaches-are-available-to-dummy-design-time-data-in-wpf?answertab=votes#tab-top), I still can't get the design time data to show up for my Windows Phone app using a `ListBox` of my custom type.

**XAML**

```
    <Page
        x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
        ...
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding MyCommunicator.MyClass}"
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <myCommunicator:MyClassDesignTime x:Key="DesignViewModel"/>
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <ListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox" d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DesignViewModel}}">
        ...
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

My custom type `MyClassDesignTime` is inherited from `MyClass`, has a parameterless constructor and static data that it returned from its properties (e.g. `Name`). I don't get any error messages when building or running my app, but during design time I cannot see any data, just a blank screen (in the "phone preview" window beside my `XAML` code.

Comment: I think you re missing <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ... /> or <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionPropertyOfViewModel}" ... />. You provide DataContext, but no ItemsSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gorgsenegger,

In my personal practise, the easiest way of providing design time data in Windows Phone/Windows Store/WPF,... projects, is to use Blend to generate some sample data.

Open your project with Blend. Go to the Data Tab, right of Blend, Create Sample Data/New Sample Data.

[image: Create datasource]

Then design your design time collection with the same properties that you expect to find in your data items.

[image: Rename properties]

Then drag the collection from the data tab to your control on the design view or the object and timeline window. Then binding code will be made.

[image]

The binding will be made :

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource FurnitureDataSource}}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"/>
```

Then you can observe your project. You will have some .xaml sample data added to your project holding the sample data that you can hand modify - or use the Data window to edit, change quantity.

You will also have a class added that represents your data and a .xsd file.

You can rework the generated code to use your class, but you'd need to arrange the xsd, file, ... I am not convinced it's the best practise. I prefer to keep two classes : mine and Blend one. 
So my class can get technically  more complicated, and sample data will always work.
Time to time I 'll have to refactor in Blend when I change a property name.

Regards

Comment: @Gorgsenegger : Did you look the response ? I think I answered your question

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late response, I was held up by problems with Windows 10 on my system and didn't get round to trying out your suggested answer until now. Works perfectly now ;-) Thanks again!