# XAML - Preview at DesignTime with Example Elemtns?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently i am using WPF XAML. I've designed a GUI in XAML and on runtime is everything fine with the binding.
There are some details which i want to modify on the GUI, but i can't perform it because i don't have any preview.

Is there a way to add some items in design time?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Blend for Visual Studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj170517.aspx

Comment: i openend blend, but there's no data tab. Is there no way directly in VS itself without having another window open? i don't like it ...

Comment: possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889966/what-approaches-are-available-to-dummy-design-time-data-in-wpf